# Can you invite another Page to 'like' your Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

There's a similar Facebook page to my own one, who I know would be interested in ours and most likely 'like' it right away if I invited them.

Without messaging them manually to ask, is there a way Facebook allows you to 'invite' another Page to 'like' yours?

In the 'Build Audience' tab in the Admin panel, all I can see is inviting friends of your own Facebook account, email contacts, or to share or promote the page to other Facebook users, but not any way to contact a *page* as such.

Answer (score 1):

At this point I do not think it is possible to invite a page to like your page. However there is a way to contact the owner of that page and ask him. You should be able to view the contact information if you go to the about section of the page, or you can simply send the owner a message on the homepage of this specific page.